Do you need to disclose that you used an LLM to convert a table from CSV to Markdown?
In I'm having difficulty comprehending the timing information presented in the CSV files of the MusicNet dataset the OP originally had a sentence

Certainly! Here's the provided data presented in a neat tabular format:

So obviously OP used an LLM tool to convert the CSV dataset to Markdown. In the comments, it was said that such usage needs to be disclosed.
The AI policy says [emphasis mine]:

What counts as “content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools”?
“Content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools” is any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided. These tools include large language models like ChatGPT and Google Gemini. Because these tools are trained to answer with language that mimics authentic speech, the responses may look and sound plausible, but the quality of generated answers can vary significantly (up to, and including, completely wrong answers).
If you are using large language model (LLM) services as described above to draft content for Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange, please ensure these are properly referenced.

With literal interpretation, the bolded parts indeed say that it needs to be disclosed. However, reading the entire policy, it seems to be about textual content, not Markdown code.

What’s clear is that at least some of that question used genAI, and that this was not properly referenced.
What’s not clear is how much.  Was it just the table formatting?  Those table headers look a bit dodgy to me; are they also AI?  Is the data is the table real?  Are any other parts of the question generated?
Our site’s AI policy says that even if the only thing the AI performed is the table formatting it should be referenced properly:

There are a few primary issues with content generated by large language models that make it unsuitable for use on Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange without properly referencing it:
[…]

Sometimes generative artificial intelligence tools may be used to assist with editing and translating content, rather than generate it. Despite this constituting a more transformative, rather than generative action, these tools are still prone to error, and they might still introduce new information not present in the original text.



In fact, the the text quoted in this question ("Certainly! Here's the provided data presented in a neat tabular format") smells rather strongly of AI.
